# Adding shadow to circular view

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to add a shadow behind a circular view, but my attempts have led me to only a shadow on my view's border—and this shadow doesn't appear all the way around the view either (just the top).  Here's my code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect{
    CGContextRef ctx=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect bounds=[self bounds];

    // Figure out the centre of the bounds rectangle
    CGPoint centre;
    centre.x=bounds.origin.x+0.5*bounds.size.width;
    centre.y=bounds.origin.y+0.5*bounds.size.height;

    // Clip context
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    // Add black outline
    path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0);

    // Specify shadow
    CGSize offset=CGSizeMake(1,4);
    CGColorRef colour=[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, offset, 2, colour);

    // Draw image
    UIImage *littleImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [littleImage drawInRect:bounds];

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there were a couple things that needed doing to fix this.  I think that this code could likely be reduced by a few lines, but here's what worked:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect{
    CGContextRef ctx=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Create bounds and path for rectangle slightly smaller than view (Thanks, Andrew T., for this!)
    CGRect bounds=[self bounds];
    CGFloat smallerBy=20.0;
    CGRect smallBounds=CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+smallerBy/2, bounds.origin.y+smallerBy/2, bounds.size.width-smallerBy, bounds.size.height-smallerBy);
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(smallBounds, NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);

    // Add black outline with shadow to bounds
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGSize offset=CGSizeMake(3,4);
    CGColorRef colour=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, offset, 8, colour);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    // Draw opaque white circle (to cover up shadow that was leaking "inside" image)
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, smallBounds);

    // Draw shadowless black outline over white circle (the circle had bitten into the original outline)
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, offset, 3, NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    // Clip context to bounds
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    // Draw image
    UIImage *newImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [newImage drawInRect:smallBounds];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're clipping the shadow. Try making the clipping path rect a little bigger or the ellipse rect a little smaller.

You can test this by turning off the clipping and see if the shadow appears.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That would explain why the shadow doesn't go all around, but the problem of the shadow appearing inside the view itself (as though the view was transparent and showing the shadow behind) would still remain... Any ideas on this one?

Comment: I think it's behaving properly because you don't fill the ellipse. It's displaying the line's shadow. If you fill the path with a solid color you won't see it.